# What is the relationship between a semi-positive definite matrix or a positive definite matrix and a convex optimization?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Can somebody give me a geometric representation of the relationship between a semi-positive definite matrix or a positive definite matrix and a convex optimization? I have been studying on this but still struggling to get the understanding of the picture about it. Some explanations and a visual representation much appreciated.

Comment: In linear programming, we minimize over the nonnegative orthant, which is a convex cone which has the nice theoretical property of being "self-dual" -- the dual cone of the nonnegative orthant is the nonnegative orthant. This self-dual property turns out to be useful in developing linear programming algorithms. The set of all positive semidefinite matrices is also a convex cone which has the property of being "self-dual". This suggests that we should consider problems like LPs but where we are minimizing over the positive semidefinite cone. Efficient LP algorithms can be extended in this way.